# Resolving ModuleNotFoundError even under the same folder without manual path addition

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, modulenotfounderror

I'm suffering from ModuleNotFoundError, even under the same folder. I'm `test_audio2coeff.py`. And within the file, I'm trying to import `audio2pose_models` module(folder). The following is tree description of my directory structure:

```
.
├── audio2exp_models
│   ├── audio2exp.py
│   ├── networks.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── audio2exp.cpython-38.pyc
│       └── networks.cpython-38.pyc
├── audio2pose_models (the module folder I want to import)
│   ├── audio2pose.py
│   ├── audio_encoder.py
│   ├── cvae.py
│   ├── discriminator.py
│   ├── networks.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── audio2pose.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── audio_encoder.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── cvae.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── discriminator.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── networks.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── res_unet.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── res_unet.py
│
├── test_audio2coeff.py (current python script)
└── utils
    ├── audio.py
    ├── croper.py
    ├── face_enhancer.py
    ├── hparams.py
    ├── init_path.py
    ├── model2safetensor.py
    ├── paste_pic.py
    ├── preprocess.py
    ├── safetensor_helper.py
    ├── text2speech.py
    └── videoio.py
```

And this is a beginning part of `test_audio2coeff.py`:

```py
import os 
import torch
import random
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import savemat
from yacs.config import CfgNode as CN
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import sys

print('__file__:    ', __file__)
print('sys_path : ', sys.path)
from audio2pose_models.audio2pose import Audio2Pose
from audio2exp_models.networks import SimpleWrapperV2 
from audio2exp_models.audio2exp import Audio2Exp
```

Then the following error occurs:

```
__file__:     /home/justin/workspace/StyleHEAT/third_part/SadTalker/src/test_audio2coeff.py
sys_path :  ['/home/justin/workspace/StyleHEAT', '/home/justin/.conda/envs/StyleHEAT/lib/python37.zip', '/home/justin/.conda/envs/StyleHEAT/lib/python3.7', '/home/justin/.conda/envs/StyleHEAT/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/justin/.conda/envs/StyleHEAT/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/justin/workspace/StyleHEAT/third_part/SadTalker']
  0%|                                                                                                   | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inference.py", line 352, in <module>
    main()
  File "inference.py", line 339, in main
    audio_reenactment(generator, data, args.audio_path)
  File "inference.py", line 86, in audio_reenactment
    from third_part.SadTalker.src.test_audio2coeff import Audio2Coeff
  File "/home/justin/workspace/StyleHEAT/third_part/SadTalker/src/test_audio2coeff.py", line 12, in <module>
    from audio2pose_models.audio2pose import Audio2Pose
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'audio2pose_models'
```

I think one solution to add path to `sys.path`, but it might be quite temporary and also very bothering to add all the paths one by one.

Can anybody explain why this happens and how to solve without manually appending paths?
Please let me know if the given information is not sufficient for you to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

What is your current working directory? Make sure that you are in the same directory as test_audio2coeff.py. You can verify your working directory by using `os.getcwd()`